# Is it possible to transform HTML into RSS with YQL?

Tags: html, rss, yql

I could do that with Yahoo Pipes, but I don't know if it is possible with YQL.

Comment: HTML into RSS? What would that look like? I'm having a hard time imagining this.

Comment: @Pekka In Yahoo Pipes you split the HTML using delimiters, for each item you use regular expressions to determine which parts will be the title, link and content of each RSS entry

Comment: @Pekka so far I could only split HTML using YQL using the DOM structure, but I couldn't generate a RSS from those items yet

Comment: What a pity! I am looking for the same feature in YQL. This is what I've found so far http://faq.netvibes.com/knowledgebase/articles/373281-how-do-i-track-updates-from-a-site-that-doesn-t-pr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YQL produces XML or JSON output. So you would need some other agent to transform either of those formats to RSS.